# How to get all the results from a flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm pretty new to working with coroutines, so bear with me. I've got the following function:

```
suspend fun getPortfolios(): Flow<Portfolio> = // ...
```

It works perfectly, returning a flow from a database using an r2dbc call. However, I want to be able to operate on the full results at once. This specific use case is related to performing assertions in a unit test, but I'm sure there are other use cases involved.

I don't want to make the code necessarily "synchronous", I just want to get all the values that would be returned by the Flow all at once in another suspend function that calls the one above.

I see there is a `collect()` function on it, but it returns a `Unit` which is very strange to me. What can I try next?

Comment: It seems you have some misconceptions about Flows. Typically you would never use a suspend function to produce and return a flow. A flow is a passive thing that only starts its work when it’s collected, so you don’t need to suspend to create it.  And you say you want it all at once, but that’s not what a flow is for. It is for retrieving a series of things over a period of time (typically). Can you show the contents of this function? Maybe you should simply be returning your results directly from the suspend function.

Comment: Sometimes flows are finite, which I typically only have seen used for UI, for example emitting a loading state followed by a data or error state. More commonly, flows that return data usually are infinite until cancelled because they are monitoring something for the most recent data.

Answer (score 3):

*sigh*. I'm leaving this post up to help others trying to learn flow, but the answer couldn't have been easier:

```
val portfolios: List<Portfolio> = getPortfolios().toList()
```